# send object through ViewData.Model in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need your help.

I tried to pass object form the view to the controller using ViewData.Model

this is the index method in the controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";
        dynamic stronglytyped = new { Amount = 10, Size = 20 };
        List<dynamic> ListOfAnynomous = new List<object> { new { amount = 10 } };


         ViewData.Model =  ListOfAnynomous[0];
        return View();
    }
```

and this is the view part

```
        <div>
             @Model.amount 

        </div>
```

this is the erro

```
'object' does not contain a definition for 'amount'
```

please could anyone help me.

Comment: Don't use `object` and `dynamic`. Create a view model and pass the view model to the view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks, I got the solution but please could you explain why the compiler does not see the dynamic object definition .

Comment: @StephenMuecke I hope to put your comment as answer to accept it

Comment: Because you passing an anonymous object. Anonymous types are internal, so their properties can't be seen outside their defining assembly. [This article](http://www.gregshackles.com/anonymous-view-models-in-asp-net-mvc-using-dynamics/) gives a good explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is thrown because you passing an anonymous object. Anonymous types are internal, so their properties can't be seen outside their defining assembly. [This article](http://www.gregshackles.com/anonymous-view-models-in-asp-net-mvc-using-dynamics/) gives a good explanation.

While you can use the html helpers to render the properties, for example

```
@Html.DisplayFor("amount")
```

you will also lose intellisense and you app will be difficult to debug.

Instead use a view model to represent what you want to display/edit and pass the model to the view.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is wrong.
If you want to use the **model** object you have pass it to the view:

```
return View(ListOfAnynomous[0]);
```

After you will be able to use the "Model" property.
ViewData is another container not related to the model property.

In the end your method will look like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";
        dynamic stronglytyped = new { Amount = 10, Size = 20 };
        List<dynamic> ListOfAnynomous = new List<object> { new { amount = 10 } };


         // ViewData.Model =  ListOfAnynomous[0];
        return View(ListOfAnynomous[0]);
    }
```