# Html.Action throwing exception: An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm getting this error from `@Html.Action("getCategory", "Blogs")` in the master layout for my blog.

The error is:

> An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.

Here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult getCategory()
    {
        var categories = _repo.getBlogs().Select(c => new
        {
            c.Category
        }).ToList();
        return PartialView("_category", categories);
    }
```

And here is my partial view:

```
@model  IEnumerable<MainSite.Data.Blog>

<div class="sw_categories">
<div class="sw_title">
    <h4>Categories</h4>
</div>
<ul class="arrows_list">
    @foreach (var c in Model)
    {
        <li><a href="#">@c</a></li>
    }
</ul>
</div>
```

I'm pretty new to ASP.NET MVC, so could anyone please explain the error to me and how I could fix this?

Comment: Is `getCategory()` returning _Blogs_ or _categories_? According to your partial it should be _Blogs_

Comment: You returning a collection of anonymous objects (which are internal so could not be accessed in the view anyway) but your view is expecting `IEnumerable<Blog>`

Comment: @Mackan Oops I've never notice that. I changed the type and it works now. Could you please post below so I can mark this as answered? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm curious about your statement "_...anonymous objects (which are internal so could not be accessed in the view anyway)_". By In206's comment, it seem that it bound fine when he changed _type_ (and by that I assume model type in the partial). I don't understand the "internal" bit you wrote, and when I don't understand I'd like to learn :) Initially I just saw this as the wrong return type: categories instead of blogs. But, as I interpret it, you're saying there is no list of categories either way (?).

Comment: I did not realize that `Select(c => new { c.Category })` in your case would return a collection of `Blog` (or was it `Category` and you changed the definition of the model in the view?). In any case, what I was referring to is explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29409811/send-object-through-viewdata-model-in-asp-net-mvc/29411446#29411446)

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke - I see what you mean, but I'm not convinced this applies here as `getBlogs()` should return Blogs, and selecting  Category from Blogs would, I assume, set the correct type. I'll have to test this :)

Comment: Yes your correct in that is does not apply here (Mackan and I were both confused by your question and what you were actually returning because it did not seem to match the model declared in the view, and if `Category` was a compley type of just a value type) - just gave you the link for information as requested

Comment: It's because categories is getting null value i.e., no value for primary key in list, so it is throwing error. debug where it is coming in your code and put if else or any suitable loop required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to either..

1. return a collection of *Blogs* from `getCategory()`, since that is what your partial is expecting:

   ```
   IEnumerable<MainSite.Data.Blog>
   ```
2. or change the model type in the partial to correspond with what you're returning from `getCategory()`. Example:

   ```
   IEnumerable<MainSite.Data.Blog.Category>
   ```