# Get data to MVC 4 View from SQL Table with using Split() method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My question would be complicated but I will try to ask clearly.

I want to keep tags in a data at SQL, as using the comma in a cell. Then, try to call two different way on my MVC 4 project. One way (basic one) is working. But another one is hard to run. I will give my codes one by one.

SQL Table: [image]

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Portfolio()
{
   return View(db.Portfolios.ToList());
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<emirhanozkan.Models.Portfolio>
@{
foreach (var pot in Model)
  {
     <p>@pot.Tags.Split(',')[0]</p>
     <p>@pot.Tags.Split(',')[1]</p>
     <p>@pot.Tags.Split(',')[2]</p>
   }
}
```

In same View one more foraech is running:

```
@foreach (var po in Model)
{
   <li class="item @po.Tags.ToLower().Trim().Replace(",","")">
      <img src="@po.Image" />
      <a href="@po.Url" target="_blank" class="md-button md-primary">@po.Title</a>
   </li>
}
```

So, What I want to do with Split method:

```
<p>AngularJS</p>
<p>MVC</p>
<p>C#</p>
<p>Wordpress</p>
<p>MVC</p>
```

I guess my `@pot.Tags.Split(',')[0]`, `@pot.Tags.Split(',')[1]` and `@pot.Tags.Split(',')[2]` code is wrong to list them but my brain not working anymore than that one. **Please help me get them like my dream.** Also, if you now to get just one from repeat words like `<p>MVC</p> <p>MVC</p>`, to just `<p>MVC</p>` **please** add to new code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestions. But I found the answer to my question:

```
@{

    foreach (var pot in Model)

{
    string str = pot.Tags;
    string[] strT = str.Split(',');
    foreach (var poo in strT) {

            <p>@poo</p>



    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop on the array returned by `Split()` method and then render the tags:

```
foreach (var pot in Model)
{
     var tags = @pot.Tags.Split(',');

      foreach(var tag in tags)
      {
        <p>@tag</p>
      }
}
```

Comment: When I tried your answer my Index page Which I showed Partial View gave and error on @{Html.RenderAction("Portfolio", "Home");}. Error: An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: From your comment it looks to me that your first reported issue has been fixed. For your new exception check this link -
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069459/html-action-throwing-exception-an-exception-of-type-system-web-httpexception

Answer (score 0):

sorry for errors, I write without compile:

```
List<Portfolio> Model = new List<Portfolio>();

StringBuilder finaltags= new StringBuilder();

foreach (var pot in Model)
{
    finaltags.AppendLine("<p>" + @pot.Tags.Split(',') + "</p>");
}
@Html.Raw(finaltags.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var pot in Model)
{
     var tags = @pot.Tags.Split(new []{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

      foreach(var tag in tags)
      {
        <p>@tag</p>
      }
}

foreach (var pot in Model)
{
  <li>
     <img src="@po.Image" />
     <a href="@po.Url" target="_blank" class="md-button md-primary">
     @po.Title</a>
  </li>
}
```